# How to insert an element inside List<>

Tags: c#, list

I have a list like this

```
var mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("apple");
mylist.Add("orange");
mylist.Add("banana");
mylist.Add("mango");
```

Now I want to add **"melon"**, between **orange** and **banana**? How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Use : `mylist.Insert(index,"melon")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Insert` method to insert new item in list. First parameter to this method is `Index` and second is the `item`.

So if you need to insert next to `orange` you need to find `index of` `orange` and insert next to this by using `IndexOf` orange.

```
mylist.Insert((mylist.IndexOf("orange") + 1), "melon");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List<T>.Insert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
mylist.Insert(2, "melon");
```

The first argument is the index at which the string should be inserted.